# How do I solve "SurfaceView: rejecting buffer" issue in android app development in python with kivyMD

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivymd

I am using python and kivyMD to use camera on android to scan QR codes, then use those to cross reference an existing google sheet, if data doesn't already exist - add new data by switching to a new screen once the code is detected and allowing user to update status. This new status will be stored in the google sheet.

I have had problems with android permissions I think. This was the logcat when I ran the .apk on multiple mobile devices:

> WindowManager           system_server            Relayout Window{623c98e u0 org.test.trackingstatusapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}: viewVisibility=0 req=1200x2000 d0
>
> BLASTBufferQueue        org.test.trackingstatusapp        SurfaceView - org.test.trackingstatusapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity@e7d97ec@0#1 rejecting buffer:active_size=1200x2000, requested_size=1200x2000 buffer{size=1200x1892 transform=0}
>
> ViewRootIm...nActivity] org.test.trackingstatusapp           Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1200,2000) new=(0,0,1200,2000) req=(1200,2000)0 dur=9 res=0x1 s={true -5476376645546594304} ch=false fn=27

This is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.lang import Builder

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient import errors

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import datetime
import copy

helper = """
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Enter new status"
    helper_text: "Press 'Submit' to register new status"
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
    size_hint: 0.75,None
    multiline: False

"""
if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission
    request_permissions([Permission.CAMERA, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
else:
    #dispose the red dot that kivy has on blank screens
    from kivy.config import Config
    Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse, disable_multitouch')



class ScannerScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScannerScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        self.image = Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        self.capture = None  # Added a variable to store the capture object
        self.event = None  # Added a variable to store the scheduled event reference
        
        self.save_img_btn = MDIconButton(
            icon='camera',
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2})
        self.save_img_btn.bind(on_press=self.change)
        layout.add_widget(self.save_img_btn)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.start_camera()

    def on_leave(self):
        self.stop_camera()

    def start_camera(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0 / 30.0)

    def stop_camera(self):
        if self.capture:
            self.capture.release()
            self.capture = None
        if self.event:
            self.event.cancel()
            self.event = None

    def change(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = 'result'

    def load_video(self, *args):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        # self.image_frame = frame  #use in case you want to make the frame available globally
        if frame is not None:
            buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
            texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
            texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.image.texture = texture

            # Decode QR code
            decoded_data = self.decode_qr_code(frame)
            # If qr code detected, then stop camera and swith to result screen
            if decoded_data:
                self.stop_camera()
                result_screen = self.manager.get_screen('result')
                result_screen.update_result(decoded_data)
                self.change(None)

    def decode_qr_code(self, frame):
        barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
        if barcodes:
            for barcode in barcodes:
                barcode_data = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
                return barcode_data
        return None


class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_y= True,
                        do_scroll_x= False,
                        size_hint= (0.8, 0.7),
                        pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 1})

        self.result_label = MDLabel(text = " ",
                                    pos_hint={'center_x': 0.72, 'center_y': 0.8},
                                    theme_text_color = "Custom",
                                    text_color=(251/255,250/255,252/255,1),
                                    font_style = 'H6')
        layout.add_widget(self.result_label)

        self.result_label_2 = MDLabel(text = "",
                                    theme_text_color = "Custom",
                                    text_color=(208/255,207/255,209/255,1),
                                    font_style = 'Body2',
                                    padding = (10,10),
                                    size_hint_y = None)
        sv.add_widget(self.result_label_2)
        layout.add_widget(sv)

        self.text_input = Builder.load_string(helper)
        layout.add_widget(self.text_input)

        self.submit_btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text = 'Submit',
                                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                                                )
        self.submit_btn.bind(on_press=self.get_data)
        layout.add_widget(self.submit_btn)


        self.back_btn = MDRectangleFlatButton(text='Keep Scanning',
                                    pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
        self.back_btn.bind(on_press=self.change)
        layout.add_widget(self.back_btn)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def change(self, instance):
        scanner_screen = self.manager.get_screen('scanner')
        self.manager.current = 'scanner'
        self.result_label_2.text = ""

    def get_data(self,*args):
        # Input from text field - user
        self.new_status = copy.deepcopy(self.text_input.text)

        self.text_input = "" #Empty text so when submit button is pressed, the text disappears

        # Add new status with timestamp
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.new_data = pd.DataFrame({0: [self.product_id],
                                1: [self.product_type],
                                2: [self.new_status],
                                3: [self.timestamp]})
        self.products = pd.concat([self.products,self.new_data], ignore_index=True)
        self.val = self.products.values.tolist()
        self.bod = {'values': self.val}
        self.results = self.service_sheets.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId = self.sheets_ID,
                                                                range = 'A1',
                                                                valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED",
                                                                body = self.bod).execute()

    def update_result(self, data):
        self.product_id, self.product_type = data.split('-')
        self.result_label.text = f"Product ID: {self.product_id}\nProduct Type: {self.product_type} " #display text in the first label field

        self.service_account_file = 'keys.json'
        self.creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename = self.service_account_file)
        self.service_sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials = self.creds)
        self.sheets_ID = #sheetID
        self.sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

        try:
            self.result = self.service_sheets.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId = self.sheets_ID,
                                                            range= self.sheet_name).execute()
            self.rows = self.result.get('values', [])
            self.products = pd.DataFrame(self.rows)
        except errors.HttpError as error:
            print(f"Error occured: {error}")
        
        if self.product_id in self.products[0].values:
            # Product ID already used, display previous statuses
            self.product_data = self.products.loc[self.products[0] == self.product_id]
            for _, row in self.product_data.iterrows():    
                self.result_label_2.text += f"Status: {row[2]}, Timestamp: {row[3]}\n" #display text in the scrollview label field

class QRApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '500'
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = 'Gray'
        self.theme_cls.accent_hue = '300'

        self.sm = ScreenManager()

        scanner_screen = ScannerScreen(name='scanner')
        result_screen = ResultScreen(name='result')

        self.sm.add_widget(scanner_screen)
        self.sm.add_widget(result_screen)

        self.sm.current = 'scanner'
        self.root = self.sm

        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    QRApp().run()
```

Could use some help, as I am a newbie at this. Thank you.

I an using the cv2 camera to capture the video, pyzbar to decode QR code and google api client to reference and edit the google sheet.